# Is it possible to add more parameter to RequestParameterMap

Tags: java, jsf

Below is how I retrieve the Request Parameter Map in JSF

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Map<String, String> requestMap = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
```

However `requestMap` is `immutable` so I can't edit it. Is there a way to add more parameters to Request Parameter Map? Is it possible at all?

Comment: Can you give some more details? Why do you want to add parameters?

Comment: No. You can add attributes to a request, but parameters are parsed once and only once when the request is gotten from the client.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would generally only do this if there was some code over which you had no control that needed such parameters. If you need to pass around request-scoped variables you should use the [request map](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequestMap%28%29).

Java EE developers generally provide additional parameters via filters. In a servlet environment, a [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) can be used to provide parameters via a [wrapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html). Portlet 2.0 containers provide a similar [filter](http://www.bluesunrise.com/portlet-api/javax/portlet/filter/package-frame.html) API.

I you want to provide custom parameter maps in a container-agnostic manner, this can be done by via a custom [ExternalContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html). Configure a custom [FacesContextFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContextFactory.html) to override the default behaviour.

See the relevant specifications for details:

- [Servlet 3.0 spec](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=315)
- [Portlet 2.0 spec](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=286)
- [JavaServer Faces 2.0 spec](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=314)

*Being more specific about why and where you want to do this in [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) might provide more useful answers.*